# Lout preprocessor writtten in python used during the production of the book entitled <C++ GUI Programming with Qt>

Tags: python, qt, preprocessor

The authors (Jasmin Blanchette & Mark Summerfield) of **`C++ GUI Programming with Qt`** has disclosed production details at the end of the book.

**Quote:**

> The authors wrote the text using NEdit and Vim. They typeset and
>   indexed the text themselves, marking it up with a modified Lout syntax
>   that they converted to pure Lout using a custom preprocessor written
>   in Python.

**References:**

- Lout official [Website](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/lout)
- Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lout_%28software%29) on Lout

**My question:**

Can somebody point to me where I can find details on such grammar derived from Lout along with its accompanying tool written in Python (a preprocessor)?

**Edit:**

Using any substitute of Lout is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found **[txt2tags](http://code.google.com/p/txt2tags/)** in Google code.

- It targets Lout.
- It's written in Python.

Comment: Hopefully it has the minimal capabilities to streamline the production of a little book using Lout.

Answer (score 1):

> Can somebody point to me where I can find details on such grammar derived from Lout?

You would be better off looking at a more established typesetting grammar like [LaTex](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/LaTeX%3aSymbols), unless you're looking for an already written Lout pre-processor.

> ...along with its accompanying tool written in Python (a preprocessor)?

If I understand correctly, Jasmin Blanchette & Mark Summerfield developed their own typesetting grammar, which they converted to Lout.  Not knowing for sure what they did, I'm assuming it was mostly symbol substitution.  To take an example from LaTex, converting `\circle` to `\bigcirc`.

After looking at Lout, I could see where it would be relatively easy to write an HTML to Lout converter.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer. Latex is not an option (Usage of Lout is mandatory). Edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @menjaraz:  What do you expect a Lout pre-processor to accomplish for you?

Comment: I know Latex is full fledged and widely used in academia, LaTeX3 development is underway (as a chess fan I've used the skak package in the past)... but I stick to Lout because of 1) it's use of high-level functional programming language, instead of a macro language, 2) its has a small footprint and overall 3) my simplistic requirements can accomodate to Lout's limited capabilities .